# How to use an mbtiles database with Android TileProvider?

Tags: android, mbtiles

What is the best way to use an mbtiles database with google's [`TileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider.html)?

I've been told that tiles as files are difficult to manage so i'm trying to use the mbtiles directly.

Comment: what is the advantage of using mbtiles instead of tiles as file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here:
https://github.com/cocoahero/android-gmaps-addons/blob/master/src/com/cocoahero/android/gmaps/addons/mapbox/MapBoxOfflineTileProvider.java

That class will do it for you.

I hope you can use it.

Comment: Super! Thank you! you just saved me a lot of work ;)