# Offline google maps from image

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, tiff, mbtiles

Ok, so, I have a .tiff file that is my image for the map. I read a bunch of tutorials and forums about it, but I cannot find a solution on how to implement this. I created the .mbtiles, tried implementing that, it doesnt work, converted the .tiff file to .png, app crashes because of out of memory, been stuck here for some time, so, if anyone knows how to implement my .tiff, .mbtiles of .png file to a google map, please share that with me.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512949/how-to-use-an-mbtiles-database-with-android-tileprovider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a custom [TileProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider) and provide your implementation using the following way:

```
mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(new MyTileProvider()));
```

I suggest you to investigate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles) similar question.